# split to preg_split?

Tags: php, split, preg-split

after 10 years with php i still S*** in regex , could you please help me converting this

```
$x_ary=split('&x=',$url);
```

to the preg_split equivalent ?

Thank you

Comment: sorry but why do u want to split the url instead of getting it using either get or post or request ?

Comment: Its a link a user inputs / read from database

Comment: @Prix: presumbly because it's not the current page's URL. But you can still parse it using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) followed by [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Comment: Its more complex than the example above , need to use preg_match if i used parse_url or explode instead of preg_split :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases you just need to add [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
 preg_split('/&x=/',$url)
```

`/` are fine if you do not need them as part of the pattern. And none of the other symbols are meta characters, so don't need escaping.

Take note that in your case you could just use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) instead, since you don't need a regex.

Comment: `explode` may indeed be better suited here.  it's definitely better performance if you're not doing anything complex...it's easily much faster than PCRE.

Comment: It might even be that OP could be interested in [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) rather.

Comment: Actually the link is more difficult than it seems , otherwise i would have just used the explode but then i need to use preg_match on every value , so preg_split just saves some lines of code and performance hopefully

Comment: @Ronan by the way, don't be afraid to use a delimiter other than the slash.  When working with URLs a lot, I find it far easier to flip to another character, just for readability's sake.  (I hate looking at a hellish amount of backslashes)  ;)